# What are currently used L2 and L3 protocols? (other than ethernet and ip4/6)

Tags: protocol-theory, transport-protocol, standardisation

I heard about plenty of alternatives to ethernet like for example token ring, ARCNET, SONET, or to IP4/6 for example IPX but once I decided to look for software and hardware support I realized those are rather historic protocols and no modern, high speed hardware is available. I know that PPP over various serial stuff and DSL family protocols are still widely used by ISP. Also some fibre protocols - GPON/GEPON.

So my question is - what are *currently used* protocols and link technologies capable of being used as interconnect between border TCP/IP networks?.

Not necessarily mainstream or super popular - but just still usable with modern hardware/software support.

Comment: SONET is still widely used.

Comment: TDM variants using HDLC, PPP, frame relay, ATM, etc. are still used. There are now 3G and 4G along with satellite, microwave, and Wi-Fi variants for wireless. There are CWDM and DWDM over fiber, and DOCSIS over cable. It can get confusing between the layer-1 and layer-2 protocols. For example, the carriers have stopped offering layer-1 frame relay, but you can still use layer-2 frame relay over TDM. IP networks really do not care about the layer-1/2 protocol(s) used.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: I tested IP over Infiniband. And plain Infiniband without IP. (Infiniband is more-or-less an Ethernet competitor but optimized for fast data transfer in supercomputing clusters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a pretty good Wikipedia article that has a list that's not exhaustive but is quite thorough - check it out [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_network_protocols_(OSI_model)).

As far as *currently* used?  It's probably safe to say that *somewhere* just about all of them are probably either encapsulated (usually in IP or MPLS) or are soldiering on forgotten in a dusty closet.  If one has *truly* died in the real world someone in a museum has resurrected a bit of it for posterity (or as a cautionary tale).